# SSDT cannot Navigate to Definition when using synonyms

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I have a stored procedure in my .sqlproj in visual studio

```
...
Select 
 a, 
 b, 
 c
from mcd_persnl
...
```

where - `mcd_persnl` - is defined as a synonym...
but when I click on `mcd_persnl` and select "navigate to definition" - is does not work..

not to speak about the warnings on column validation...

Is this by design - or it's my environment that's broken ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't navigate either so I guess it isn't your environment that is broken.

If you raise a microsoft connect issue I will vote it up at least, post the link here.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/

(Add it under developer tools SSDT etc)

ed

Comment: it seems like a different one to me but i've voted that one as well :)